# is the value of java class object same as class name?

Tags: java

Hi i am a beginner in java programming and was having trouble understanding what a value of an object would be. I was debugging the following program and while looking under the variables tab in eclipse I saw variable name as ex and value as Exception. I did not understand if the instance of a class has a value same as class name. 
can somebody please help.

```
public void abc(int i)throws Exception{
    i++;
    throw new Exception("Exception");
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    try{
        Test t = new Test();
        t.abc(5);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That just means that the object that is currently stored in the `ex` variable is of type `Exception`... that is, `ex` is non-null. The exception object itself probably has some fields associated with it that you can look at if you expand the variable's description in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of exception is whatever you pass to its constructor:

```
throw new Exception("Exception");
```

As you pass string "Exception", you see the same as `ex` value later.

In general the better way to print exception is to use its `printStackTrace` method which gives much more details why it happened:

```
 ex.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but I remember that an object value should be a reference to the object for which the instance method or default method was invoked, or to the object being constructed. In that case shouldn't the object ex be a reference to some instance method? why is its value same as the argument passed?

Comment: @MrsB : not sure what you mean. Here your IDE shows whatever toString() returns. For Exception its usually its description. And the description is the argument you passed to this Exception constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the instance of the class `Exception` has value "Exception". You have set it in `abc` method. If you change the value in the constructor of the Exception class like:

```
throw new Exception("Some value");
```

You will have that "Some value" as a result.

Comment: thank you. So if I am asked the value of ex will it be "Some value" (the argument I gave for constructor) or Exception(the type of the object)

Comment: It will be the argument you gave in the constructor. If you leave the constructor empty the value will be default one. For more information try here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html